# No mapping found for URL ... 404

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, mapping

I try to get model element from my controller to frontend. I'm using very simple objects.
se.no.controllers.UserController

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public User register(@RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println("Register!!");
        return user;
    }
...
```

Ajax front

> ```
>   var user = {
>           name :  $('#username').val(),
>           password :  $('#password').val(),
>   };
>
>
>   jQuery.ajax({
>       url : context.get('root') + '/register',
>       type : "POST",
>       contentType: 'application/json',
>       dataType: 'json',
>       data : JSON.stringify(user),        
>       success : function(resp) {   ...
> ```

web.xml

```
<display-name>WebApp</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error404</location>
</error-page>
```

and spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="se.no.controllers,se.no.controllers,se.no.service,se.no.dao" /> 

<!-- also add the following beans to get rid of some exceptions -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.lang.Exception">error</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean> 

<tx:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- the mvc resources tag does the magic -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Could you tell me what im missing? The result which i get is:

> 404 Not Found - localhost:8080/sklepi/register"

I'm mapping everything while running application

> INFO: Mapped URL path [/register] onto handler 'userController'

When im returning view, not the model, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this:

```
url : context.get('root') + '/register',
```

is returning your correct url? If not, you can use `<%=request.getContextPath()%>/register` instead, if your front-end is built with JSP.

If it's still not working, try to remove these three mappings:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And use only the first one:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you are using `/*` it's not necessary to declare the rest.

Comment: Url equals '/sklepi/register'. I removed additional mappings, but nothing changed.

Comment: Your mapping is /register, why your URL is /sklepi/register? That should be your mapping URL

Comment: /sklepi is from application name. For example when im loading view i do /sklepi/index and everything works, but when i do the same for this kind of method, i got 404